# Measuring periodicity strength of a specific time on the time series data

Tags: time-series, data-mining, period, periodicity

I try to measure periodicity strength of a specific time on the time series data when a period (e.g., 1day, 7day) is given.

For example,

```
      | AM 10:00 | 10:30 | 11:00 |
DAY 1 |     A    |   A   |   B   |
DAY 2 |     A    |   B   |   B   |
DAY 3 |     A    |   B   |   B   |
DAY 4 |     A    |   A   |   B   |
DAY 5 |     A    |   A   |   B   |
```

If a period is 1 day, AM 10:00 and 11:00 is the highest strength of periodicity in this data because there are consistent value in both times.

Are there any popular method or research to do this?

There are many existed research for finding periodic pattern in the time series, but I can't find research measuring periodicity strength of a specific time when a period is given.

Please sharing your knowledge. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is something called [cyclic association rules](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/3735030_Cyclic_association_rules). I've linked to the paper that was originally written by researches at Bell Labs.